# Date only limited function class

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Per the title date only class (or struct?).

.NET does not offer a date only data type.

I get there is time zone dynamic but then you have daylight-savings that can still kill you. I do document management and we just have a document with a date.

```
// minimal limited test
DateOnly date1 = new DateOnly(1901, 2, 1);
DateOnly date2 = new DateOnly(1902, 3, 2);
DateOnly date3 = new DateOnly(1902, 3, 2);
Debug.WriteLine(date1.GetDayDiff(date2));  // 365 + 29 = 394
Debug.WriteLine(date2.GetDayDiff(date1));
Debug.WriteLine(date2.CompareTo(date1));
Debug.WriteLine(date1.CompareTo(date2));
Debug.WriteLine(date2.CompareTo(date3));
// end test

public class DateOnly: Object, IComparable
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> MonthDay = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 31 }, { 2, 29 }, { 3, 31 }, { 4, 30 },  { 5, 31 },  { 6, 30 }
                                                                       , { 7, 31 }, { 8, 31 }, { 9, 30 }, { 10, 31 }, { 11, 30 }, { 12, 31 } };
    public override int GetHashCode() { return (Int32)Days; }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        DateOnly other = (DateOnly)obj;
        return (this.Days == other.Days);
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (obj is DateOnly)
        {
            DateOnly other = (DateOnly)obj;
            if (other == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
            return (this.Days).CompareTo(other.Days);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Year, Month, Day);
    }
    public Int64 GetDayDiff(DateOnly Date)
    {
        Int64 getDayDiff = (Int64)this.Days - (Int64)Date.Days;
        return (getDayDiff);
    }
    public UInt32 Days    { get; private set; }
    public int Year       { get; private set; }
    public int Month      { get; private set; }
    public int Day        { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 MaxDays { get; private set; } 
    public DateOnly(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        if (!ValidateDate(year, month, day))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("invalid date");
        MaxDays = GetDays(2078, 12, 31) - 1;
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
        Day = day;
        Days = GetDays(year, month, day);
    }
    private bool ValidateDate(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        if (year < 1900 || year >= 2079)
            valid = false;
        else if (month < 1 || month > 12)
            valid = false;
        else if (day < 1 || day > 31)
            valid = false;
        else if (day > DaysPerMonth(year, month))
            valid = false;
        return valid;
    }
    private UInt32 GetDays(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        UInt32 days = 0;
        int yearSince1900 = year - 1900;
        UInt32 temp;
        for (int i = 1; i <= yearSince1900; i++)
        {
            temp = DaysPerYear(i + 1900 - 1);
            days += temp;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= month; i++)
        {
            temp = DaysPerMonth(year, i - 1);
            days += temp;
        }
        days += (UInt32)day;
        return days;
    }
    private bool IsLeap(int year)
    {
        return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0);
    }
    private UInt32 DaysPerYear(int year)
    {
        if (IsLeap(year))
            return 366;
        else
            return 365;
    }
    private UInt32 DaysPerMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        UInt32 days = (UInt32)MonthDay[month];
        if (month == 2 && !IsLeap(year))
            days = 28;
        return days;
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant to use Uint16 for the backing field.  That is why is limited to 1900-2078.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Properly overriding `GetHashCode()`

I remember when first learning how to properly override and use `GetHashCode()`, that there was a rule that stated ***The integer returned by GetHashCode() should never change***. You're violating this rule because `Days` is not a `readonly` property.

### Bad practices and unnecessary code

1. Take a look at this snippet:

> ```
> public int CompareTo(object obj)
> {
>     if (obj == null)
>     {
>         throw new ArgumentNullException();
>     }
>     if (obj is DateOnly)
>     {
>         DateOnly other = (DateOnly) obj;
>         if (other == null)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentNullException();
>         }
>         return (this.Days).CompareTo(other.Days);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         throw new ArgumentNullException();
>     }
> }
> ```

There are 2 problems in this method.

First - you're using the `is` operator combined with a direct cast, instead of using the `as` operator.

Second - you have a redundant if statement that will never be triggered - `if (other == null)`, if the cast (`DateOnly other = (DateOnly) obj;`) fails it will crash your program, it wont return null.

And lastly you don't really need an `else` statement there as there is flow branching involved if you trigger the `if` statement you will eventually reach the `return` statement which will break out of the method, thus not even continuing down your code, making the `else` redundant.

This is how I would write this method:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    var other = obj as DateOnly;
    if (other != null)
    {
        return (this.Days).CompareTo(other.Days);
    }
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

2. In `GetDayDiff(DateOnly Date)` you perform 2 casts when only 1 is necessary to operate with the proper type:

> ```
> long getDayDiff = (long) this.Days - (long) Date.Days;
> ```

You can just do:

```
long getDayDiff = this.Days - (long) Date.Days;
```

3. I'm not sure why you inherit from `object`, this is unnecessary, as every type in C# inherits from that class whether it will be explicitly stated changes nothing, it's just few extra letters.

### Shortening the code

1. You can use interpolated strings instead of `String.Format()`:

> `return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Year, Month, Day);`

As interpolated string:

```
return $"{Year}/{Month}/{Day}";
```

2. Ternary operator:

You can make use of the ternary operator here:

> ```
> if (IsLeap(year))
>     return 366;
> else
>     return 365;
> ```

Like this:

```
return (uint) (IsLeap(year) ? 366 : 365);
```

### Overall design

Few concerns here:

1. I would just use `DateTime` as a backing field and utilise some of the already written methods there (I'm sure this was a design pattern but I cant think of the name right now, maybe Decorator?).
2. You lack range checks and overall validation of your public methods.
3. You're inconsistent with where you use `uint` and `int`, if you've decided that it would be good to use `uint` because x, y, z, why are you not using that everywhere? This will also partially solve point 2.

Comment: How is get; private set; not read only?  DateTime is 64 bites and don't need or want  time or time zone here.   Public method with a private set does not need a range check.  Inherit from Object is so equal properties are equal.

Comment: @Paparazzi, `private set` and `readonly` properties share only 1 similarity, the place where you can set they're value is in the containing class itself, the difference is that you can set the value of a `private set` property anywhere you like in your class, where the `readonly` property can receive value only in the constructor or at initialization.  I'm not sure what you mean by *Inherit from Object is so equal properties are equal*, inheriting from `Object` explicitly changes absolutely nothing, your class will **always** inherit from `Object`.

Comment: I thought you had to implement Object to override GetHashcode and Equals.

Comment: I am using Uint32 for Days to get the longest possible date range in 4 bytes.   I made all the  changes you suggested.   Thanks   Going to leave it up for 2 days before accepting an answer.

Comment: I messed up.  I meant for the backing to be Uint16 but all your point are still valid.