# Equality for a DateOfBirth Value Object

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
public sealed class DateOfBirth : IEquatable<DateOfBirth>, IComparable<DateOfBirth>
    {
        private readonly DateTime _value;

        public DateTime Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }
        public DateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)
        {
            if(dateOfBirth == DateTime.MinValue)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value.", "DateOfBirth");
            this._value= dateOfBirth;
        }

        private static int Comparison(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2))
                return 0;
            else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null))
                return -1;
            else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth2, null))
                return 1;
            if (dateOfBirth1._value < dateOfBirth2._value)
                return -1;
            else if (dateOfBirth1._value == dateOfBirth2._value)
                return 0;
            else if (dateOfBirth1._value > dateOfBirth2._value)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        public int CompareTo(DateOfBirth other)
        {
            if (other != null)
                return this._value.CompareTo(other._value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentNullException("DateOfBirth");
        }


        public static bool operator ==(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) == 0;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return !(dateOfBirth1 == dateOfBirth2);
        }

        public static bool operator <(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) < 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) > 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) <= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) >= 0;
        }

        public bool Equals(DateOfBirth other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
                return false;
            return _value == other._value;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as DateOfBirth);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

I realise it could be argued as over engineering a simple date of birth field.  I am more interested whether or not the nine comparisons (https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/) are implemented correctly.  This article helped me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/10/11/c-comparison-operator-overloading-and-spaceship-operator/ - the only concern I have about the code in this article is that the `Comparison` method does not do this (which my code does):

```
if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2))
                return 0;
            else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null))
```

Q1) Is the code above fit for purpose (are there any bugs)?

Q2) Is a DateTime data type (DateOfBirth._value) suitable for a Date of Birth?
                    return -1;

Q3) Is the validation in the constructor fit for purpose?

Comment: My .Net knowledge is a little dated (no pun intended), but it seems like it would be easier to have `class DateOfBirth extends DateTime {}` and leave it at that.  You are more or less creating an exact copy of DateTime under a different name.

Comment: DateTime is a struct, which does not support inheritance

Comment: I figured there would be something.  One could still map all the functions to call the underlying DateTime methods instead. E.g. `bool Equals(object obj) { return _value.Equals(obj); }`, `bool operator <=(DateOfBirth dob1, DateOfBirth dob2) { return dob1.Value <= dob2.Value; }`, etc.  You could even declare DateOfBirth as a struct instead of a class, and/or give it an implicit cast to DateTime so that for all the functions expecting a DateTime, you could pass DateOfBirth directly without having to call .Value

Comment: I don't see where _value is assigned.

Comment: @Paparazzi in `public DateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)`: `this._value= dateOfBirth;`

Comment: I am with other comments.  Why not just use DateTime.   You are not removing the time component.

Comment: I wrote a Date class.  Not great but here it is.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159208/date-only-limited-function-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 'fit for purpose' depends on what exactly that purpose is. Do you want to register the time of birth (as the `Value` property suggests), or only the date (as the class name seems to imply)? Does it need to handle birth dates before 0 A.D.? Does it need to reject non-existing dates (depending on actual historical data)?
- If this class is meant to store a date only (not a time component), then it makes more sense to give it `Year`, `Month` and `Day` properties, rather than a `Value` property that exposes a time component.
- `DateTime.MinValue` is the default value of `DateTime`, but why does that make it an invalid birth-date?
- It may be useful to provide (explicit or implicit) conversions operators from and to `DateTime`, and perhaps parsing methods, depending on where and how this class is meant to be used. However...
- ...the purpose of this class seems *very* narrow. Judging from your other posts, you are thinking about creating many such 'value' types? That's a lot of work (at least in C#), but what problem does it solve? Where's the added value? Are you worried that someone may accidentally assign an expiry-date to a birth-date field? Remember, all that extra code needs to be maintained, and there's a cost associated with that.

My impression is that yes, you are over-engineering this. I suspect that you'll find more value in writing automated tests (which, when done properly, should have caught that `>=` operator bug, and should catch expiry-date/birth-date mixups just as well) than in adding this sort of complexity. C# requires too much boiler-plate to make this approach viable, so unless lives are at stake I wouldn't bother.

---

EDIT: A few more notes:

- In C# 7, `ReferenceEquals(a, null)` can be written more succinctly as `a is null`.
- The null check in `CompareTo` uses the overloaded `!=` operator, but you might as well use a reference check directly.
- Why are the `Equals` methods not using `Comparison`? The same goes for the `!=` operator: why doesn't it do `Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) != 0`?

Comment: The purpose is to remove primitive obsession and make the domain model easier to talk about with a Business Analyst.  Plus the validation is in one place.  Do you still think it is an overkill?

Comment: You're simply replacing primitive obsession with value type obsession. Why would `public DateOfBirth DateOfBirth { get; }` make talking with a business analyst easier than `public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; }`? If they say: 'Why do birth-dates contain a time? They shouldn't', then replace `DateTime` with a general-purpose `Date` type. But I see no point in duplicating `DateTime`.

Comment: If I used three properties for the date then what would I expose via getters i.e. three integers or a datetime.

Comment: Just think about what a date is: it's a year, month and day, right? So I'd expect a `Date` class to have a property for each of those. A date does not contain a time, so a `DateTime` property would only be confusing.

Comment: Thanks.  So the using code would have to get all three properties and then formulate a datetime?

Comment: If using code needs a `DateTime` in the first place, why is it using a `Date` class? Either way, if you often need to convert between the two, then it makes sense to provide conversion operators or methods (`var dateTime = (DateTime)date;`, or `var dateTime = date.ToDateTime();`, or something like that).

Comment: No upvotes yet? This isn't right... If there only was such class as `Date`.  In most languagues there isn't so `DateTime` is used for everything. I don't like it either but the alternative of creating your own class without the time part is just too much work. JavaScript is even uglier because its `Date` also contains time :-o

Comment: @t3chb0t there is always [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html). Having spent time with F#, I do rather wish I could one-line these sorts of types (i.e. which just wrap a name over another type, providing a decompose method (`Value`) and precluding cross-assignment); however, given the overhead, I agree with the answers that it is rarely worth it.

Comment: I have written another similar question here if you are interested: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186989/date-of-birth-value-object-2

Answer (score 2):

#### ctor

It looks strange that the passed `DateTime` parameter is named `dateOfBirth`. A reader of the code could get confused because mostly you use `DateOfBirth dateOfBirthX` wher `X` stands for either `1` or `2`.

#### CompareTo()

The code doesn't comply with the documentation of [`IComparable<T>.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx) which states in the remarks

> By definition, any object compares greater than null, and two null references compare equal to each other.

meaning if `other == null`  the method should return a value `> 0`. Throwing an exception would be quite confusing if e.g you have a `List<DateOfBirth>`, where it is legal to add `null`, and try to `Sort()` to get an `ArgumentNullException`.

#### Comparision()

This method should be simplified because you don't need to check if `dateOfBirth1._value == dateOfBirth2._value` if you at the end of the method return `0` anyway.

While we are at this `if..else if..else if....` you should do yourself a favour and use braces `{}` although they might be optional. Omitting braces can lead to hidden and therfor hard to find bugs.

```
private static int Comparison(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2))
    {
        return 0;
    {
    else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth2, null))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (dateOfBirth1._value < dateOfBirth2._value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (dateOfBirth1._value > dateOfBirth2._value)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree what the other two answers. This class doesn't add anything that would make it more useful than the ordinary `DateTime`.

---

Other issues that weren't addressed yet are...

> ```
> public DateTime Value
> {
>     get { return _value; }
> }
> ```

Introducing this property makes working with the `DateOfBrith` just more confusing. It gives the user a direct access to the underlaying data. This undermines the entire purpose of encapsulating and *hiding* the date-of-birth as a pure `DateTime`.

---

But not only that. It also uses pretty unhelpful exceptions:

> ```
> public DateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)
> {
>     if(dateOfBirth == DateTime.MinValue)
>         throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value.", "DateOfBirth");
>     this._value= dateOfBirth;
> }
> ```

The `ArgumentException` already means that some value was invalid so writing it as a message doesn't help. I expect you to tell me why it was invalid and what should I use to make it valid again. The other argument is also misleading. The argument name is `dateOfBirth` and not `DateOfBirth`. You should be using `nameof()` here anyway. Nobody uses such harcoded strings anymore.

---

> ```
> public int CompareTo(DateOfBirth other)
> {
>     if (other != null)
>         return this._value.CompareTo(other._value);
>     else
>         throw new ArgumentNullException("DateOfBirth");
> }
> ```

The other exception is even worse because it does not only change the case like the first one but it uses an entirely different name! It should be `other` and not `DateOfBirth`.

But as @Heslacher said, this shouldn't be even throwing any exceptions.

---

> ```
> (DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
> ```

I find the names of the arguments a little bit weird. By convention they are usually named `left` and `right` for where they come from or `x` and `y` and not some *name+number*.

---

The implementation is also inconsitent. You redirect all operators to `Comparison` but reinvent the wheel here

> ```
> public bool Equals(DateOfBirth other)
> {
>     if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
>         return false;
>     return _value == other._value;
> }
> ```

by doing exactly the same equality check as you already did earlier.

Comment: Thanks.  If I don't expose a datetime value to the calling code then how do they know what the value encapsulated is?

Comment: @w0051977 that's the whole point. You either should have explicitly cast it to `DateTime` or use your class everywhere. It would be quite pointless to use the `Value` because then you can easily avoid the entire encapsulation and you can use a `DateTime` instead without loosing anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I originally asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582699/equality-for-a-dateofbirth-value-object, but then deleted that question to ask here instead.  I have undeleted the question.  Please see Pieter Witvoet comment.

Comment: @w0051977: with 'observing the actual date' I meant being able to inspect its year, month and day (that's what a date is, right?), not exposing an internal implementation detail (its `DateTime` field).