# Date of Birth Value Object 2

Tags: c#

I realize it could be argued that it is an overkill to create a ValueObject for such a simple type. I am just trying to make sure that I understand the principles of overriding/overloading these methods correctly. I would be grateful for some critical feedback. Specifically:

1. Are all the methods implemented correctly?
2. Have I compared the date of births correctly i.e. `if (candidate.AddYears(21).Date > DateTime.Now.Date)` assuming that I am using the western idea of age.

Please note that with regards to naming conventions; I have used what is advised [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling/)

```
public sealed class DateOfBirth
    {
        private readonly DateTime _value;
        public DateOfBirth(DateTime value)
        {
            if (value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds > 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Date of birth cannot contain a time.", "DateOfBirth");
            if (IsValid(value) == true)
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }

        public DateOfBirth(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            var value = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            if (IsValid(value)==true)
            {
                _value = value;
            }     
        }

        public static bool IsValid(DateTime candidate)
        {
            if (candidate.AddYears(21).Date > DateTime.Now.Date) 
                throw new ArgumentException("Age must be greater than 21.", "DateOfBirth");
            return true;
        }

        public DateTime Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as DateOfBirth);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static implicit operator DateTime(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
        {
            return dateOfBirth._value;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null) &&
                ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth2, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null) &&
                 !ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth2, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null) &&
                 ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth2, null))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return dateOfBirth1.Equals(dateOfBirth2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return !(dateOfBirth1 == dateOfBirth2);
        }

        public bool Equals(DateOfBirth other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
                return false;
            return _value == other._value;
        }
    }
```

Note: this is a follow-up question [to this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186590/equality-for-a-dateofbirth-value-object).

Comment: `"Age must be greater than 21."` this is a really weird condition for a date-of-birth ;-| You probably should rename the class to be a `CanHaveDrivingLicenseDateOfBirth` or something like that.

Comment: @t3chb0t, thanks.  I will do that.  Is there anything else?

Comment: @t3chb0t: `CanHaveDrivingLicenseDateOfBirth` isn't particularly better. Not only does that create a dependency on local legislature (I don't know any country where you need to be 21 to have a driving license), there's also no reason to suddenly mention driving licences purely because the currently set age limit _happens_ to be the same as the age for getting a driving license (supposedly, since I still don't know the country you're referring to). It makes as much sense as `MoreThanTheTenfoldOfMyHouseNumberDateOfBirth`, since my house number happens to be 2 at the moment.

Comment: @Flater I'm not referring to any country and I think you take my example too literally. This exaggeration should just show that the strange age constraint should somehow be addressed  by the class name.

Comment: @t3chb0t: In general, I can't see any argument in favor of giving a data class (as opposed to e.g. a validator class) a classname which includes the adherence to an arbitrary businessrule, regardless of the rule in question.

Comment: @Flater well, when I see a class with such a generic name as `DateOfBirth` I expect it to work with any date. However, if it suddenly throws at me an exception for someone who was born yesterday, I'd throw this code back at whoever has written it ;-]

Comment: I would argue that if you want to have the class enforce some age restriction, make that a property and let the client set it. Then you can call it `RestrictedDOB` or something, and the client could do something like `var drinkingAge = new RestrictedDOB { minAge = 21 };` or `var drivingAge = new RestrictedDOB { minAge = 16 };` or `var childrenOnly = new RestrictedDOB { maxAge = 12 };`

Comment: `IsValid` should return `true` or `false`, not throw an exception. You could rename it to `ThrowIfInvalid`, but otherwise it is misleading. Can you imagine if `string.IsNullOrEmpty` threw an exception if the argument was null or empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating such objects is generally a good idea and I often do it myself **but** they have to offer me some advantages over using a primitive. In case of this code I don't see them and the examples you linked give bad advices.

> ```
> public static implicit operator DateTime(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
> {
>     return dateOfBirth._value;
> }
> ```

This is what I consider the most dangerous operator of such objects because I'll allow you to silently *convert* it into a primitve so you won't notice it when you loose the benefits of your custom *ValueObject*. In my opinion this should always be explicit.

---

> ```
> public static bool IsValid(DateTime candidate)
> ```

I don't support the idea of having this method public and I cannot think of any case where it would be useful. If I create my value-object I either expect it to throw an exception or to have an exception-free `TryDoSomething`. `IsValid` woudld mean I have to implement `TryDoSomething` myself.

---

> "Age must be greater than 21."

Because of this strange constraint this class shouldn't be named just `DateOfBirth`. It looks more like a `CanHaveDrivingLicenseDateOfBirth` or `CanDrinkAlcoholDateOfBirth`. It needs a much stronger name.

---

Implementing such types means a lot of work in terms of overriding all the equality methods. In order to save you some time you should have a base type `Date` or `Name` that already implements all the basic and mandatory logic and if necessary just override it in the derived class and add to it in your `CanMarryDateOfBirth` or `LastName`.

---

Other issues in your code are in the constructors.

> ```
> public DateOfBirth(DateTime value)
> {
>     if (value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds > 0)
>         throw new ArgumentException("Date of birth cannot contain a time.", "DateOfBirth");
>     if (IsValid(value) == true)
>     {
>         _value = value;
>     }
> }
>
> public DateOfBirth(int year, int month, int day)
> {
>     var value = new DateTime(year, month, day);
>     if (IsValid(value)==true)
>     {
>         _value = value;
>     }     
> }
> ```

They aren't chained and consequently they repeat the same code twice.

Comment: Can you give some examples where an object is beneficial over a primitive? Complex validation i.e. post code is one I guess? If I was going for a pure DDD approach (which I am not) then would it be advisable to always create these value objects instead of using primitives?

Comment: @w0051977 the simplest example: `Name`, I think of it as a case-insensitive and trimmed string that causes a lot of trouble if not implemented once and for all but all around the place.

Comment: And if I was using the ddd approach as a purist, then would I always use these value objects?

Comment: I don't think that C#'s type system is an appropriate place to encode rules like this (not all of them anyway). Marriageable age, for example, depends on country, time in history, and maybe other factors as well, so you may end up with an explosion of types. Eric Lippert wrote an interesting series of articles about this: [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/).

Answer (score 2):

### Design:

- I still think that a `DateOfBirth` class is too narrow. It should be the name of a property, not a separate class. If you must create a class, create a reusable `Date` class instead. Enforcing this sort of restrictions at the type level isn't worth the extra work and maintenance cost (in C#). That's my opinion, of course, but judging by your many questions it really is a lot of work, isn't it? ;)
- I expect a `DateOfBirth.IsValid` method to check whether the given input is a valid *birth-date*. That is, I expect it to reject nonsense input like '-5 45 2018'. However, your implementation enforces a *business rule* instead. There are several problems with that:

  - It's confusing: it's basically telling me that '7 februari 2018' is not a valid birthdate.
  - It's inflexible: what if some logic applies to people above 21, but other logic only to people below 18?
- Again, why expose `Value` directly? As I mentioned before, a date does not have a time component, but by exposing a `DateTime` property you make it look like it does. Of course, you may want to *convert* between dates and date-times, but that's what conversion operators are for. A `Year`, `Month` and `Day` property are far more in line with what a date actually *is*. Look at `DateTime`, for example: it uses a timestamp as internal storage, but it provides meaningful properties like `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minute`, `Second`, and so on, which results in a much more natural and practically useful interface.
- Where did the comparison operators go? Are they superseded by the `IsValid` method? Or are you planning to use `Value` for that? If so, why create a separate class in the first place?

### Implementation:

- No need for `== true`: `IsValid` already returns a boolean.
- The constructors do not throw if validation fails: they fall back to a 'default' value instead. That's very surprising behavior, in a bad way. It's also inconsistent, because some input does produce an exception. (EDIT: Excuse me, they do throw, because `IsValid` throws - so that underlines the point below! `ThrowIfInvalid` would be a more appropriate method name.)
- Why does `IsValid` throw an exception? Its signature suggests that it will only return true/false. Such unexpected behavior makes code more difficult to work with.
- The value property can be written more succinctly as `public DateTime Value => _value;`, but you could also use a get-only property instead.
- You may want to mention which version of C# you're using. I mentioned the `a is null` improvement from C#7, but I don't see that applied here
  so I guess you're still stuck with an older version?

Finally, the `==` operator can be simplified:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) != ReferenceEquals(b, null))
{
    return false;       // One is null, the other is not
}
else if (ReferenceEquals(a, null))
{
    return true;        // Both are null
}
else
{
    return a.Equals(b); // Both are not null
}
```

Comment: `if/else if/else` alarm! it'd be nicer with `if`s only :-)

Comment: @t3chb0t: ah yes, early-outs. I just chose `if/else` because it's a stronger indication that the checks depend on each other.

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet, This is more of a learning exercise for me rather than an actual requirement.  I am trying to understand when to introduce objects and when not to introduce objects.  I asked a question here about it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365234/initialise-a-date-of-birth-with-a-datetime-or-three-integers.  The answerers all seemed to agree that I should create an object in this case.  Do you agree with what they say?

Comment: @w0051977: in that question you were asking about type aliasing, and I agree with them that aliasing isn't useful. Also, they recommend either creating a general-purpose `Date` class (not a specialized `DateOfBirth` class) or just using the existing `DateTime`.

Comment: @w0051977: Also, which is better depends on a lot of factors. Are dates part of the core functionality of your application? How large and skilled is your team? How much time do you have? What's the expected lifetime of this application? Without providing that context, you're probably going to get a lot of conflicting opinions, that may or may not apply to your particular situation.

Comment: @w0051977 I looked at the other answer. They recommended using a `DateTime`.